# Запуск DJANGO на VPS сервере

Tags: python, django

У меня на сайте есть парсер. Когда я разрабатывал проект локально, то у меня парсер включался в файле `manage.py`. Когда я сайт закинул на vps сервер, то парсер перестал включаться. Как я понимаю, на сервере не запускается файл `manage.py`. А что тогда запускается? Как мне включится парсер с проектом одновременно? Может его запускать, как отдельный файл?

Comment: А почему вы решили, что он должен включаться? Что вы предприняли для того, чтобы он включался?

Comment: Ничего. Я просто думал, что проект запускается также, как и на локальном, только там доп. настройки.

Comment: То, как запускается проект на vps, настраиваете и решаете лично вы. Что конкретно вы уже настроили и запустили?

Comment: У меня настроено все, проект работает, но парсер, который включался в файл manage.py нет

Comment: Как именно настроено и как именно работает? Какая операционная система стоит хотя бы?

Comment: Всмысле как, я не понимаю? Настроен supervisor и nginx, ОС: linux

Comment: Вот значит в тот же самый supervisor добавьте ещё одну команду, которая будет запускать ваш парсер

Comment: А как добавить вторую команду? Создать вторую программу в supervisor?

Comment: Видимо да, [документация supervisor](http://supervisord.org/running.html) вам в помощь

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Тем не менее, меня очень смущает фраза «парсер включался в файле manage.py» — что конкретно подразумвается под этим? Если парсер оформлен в виде [нормальной management-команды](https://habr.com/ru/post/415049/), тогда проблем с запуском этой команды быть не должно, но если вы вдруг навелосипедили что-то нестандартное, то, возможно, вы создали себе проблем на пустом месте

Comment: У меня через Thread запускалась функция с парсером, чтобы при запуске проекта сразу включался парсер. Этот парсер работает все время, без остановки ,поэтому я принял решение сделать его в файл manage.py

Comment: Это вы зря, такой подход плохо совместим с архитектурой WSGI-приложений (каковым Django и является), рекомендую переделать на management-команду чтобы не страдать

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо